# BootstrapVue b-table not storing selected rows when changing pages using b-pagination

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have the following `b-table` and `b-pagination` in my template:

```
<b-table
  bordered
  hover
  responsive
  :items="items"
  :fields="fields"
  :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
  :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
  sort-icon-left
  :filter="searchFilter"
  @filtered="onFiltered"
  :filter-included-fields="filterOn"
  :per-page="perPage"
  :current-page="currentPage"
  class="table1"
  ref="table1"
  selectable
  @row-selected="selectedRow"
  :tbody-tr-class="styleRow"
>
  <template #cell(selected)="{ rowSelected }">
      <template v-if="rowSelected">
          <span class="sr-only">Selected</span>
      </template>
      <template v-else>
          <span class="sr-only">Not selected</span>
      </template>
  </template>
</b-table>

<b-pagination
  v-model="currentPage"
  :total-rows="totalRows"
  :per-page="perPage"
  align="center"
  limit="15"
></b-pagination>
```

In my `Vue` app, I have the following functions for when the user selects a row:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      sortBy: 'build',
      sortDesc: true,
      searchFilter: '',
      perPage: 11,
      currentPage: 10,
      totalRows: 1,
      fields: [],
      defaultFields: [],
      fieldNames: [],
      filterOn: [],
      selectedInfo: { item: {}, value: {}, field: {} },
      selected: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    styleRow(item) {
      if (item.selected) {
        return ['b-table-row-selected', 'table-secondary'];
      }
      return [];
    },
    selectedRow(items) {
      this.selected = items;
    }
  },
};
```

Here's the problem: let's say the user selects a few rows on page 1 of the table, then goes to page 2, and then goes back to page 1. The previously clicked rows are no longer selected. How do I fix this? How do I prevent pagination from resetting the selected rows?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [BootstrapVue documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#row-select-support), Sorting/filtering/paginating the table will clear the active selection. The row-selected event will be emitted with an empty array ([]) if needed.

My suggestion is to store the selected rows to another variable (eg: selectedList: []) on row-selected, so that it will not emitted with an empty array when pagination trigerred. Then, append the selectedList on [refreshed Event](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-events), so that when you go to next page or ack to previous page, selectedList variable will hold all rows you've selected.